# Go error: gob: type sync.Mutex has no exported fields

Tags: go, mutex, gob

I am having an issue where I can't save a struct as a gob if it has an exported `sync.Mutex`. Everything seems to work if I make the mutex unexported (by not capitalizing it). I'm curious to understand why this is and make sure that there's no other issue with gobbing an unexported `sync.Mutex`.

I see that there are several hits on Google for a related problem with `sync.RWMutex`, but none really explain why this happens.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "encoding/gob"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func writeGob(filePath string, object interface{}) error {
    file, err := os.Create(filePath)
    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(file)
    err = encoder.Encode(object)
    return err
}

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    GobMux sync.Mutex
}

func main() {
    d := &Dog{Name: "Fido"}
    err := writeGob("./gob", d)
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
}
```

Output:

> Error: gob: type sync.Mutex has no exported fields

Comment: There's an open issue on this problem:  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5819

Comment: Gotcha. One follow up question: when I read back a Dog object from a gob, it looks like the mutex is unlocked regardless of the state of the mutex when it was saved to a gob. Is this behavior I can count on?

Comment: You should not count on a deserialized mutex at all. It's conceptually pointless - whatever process serialized it can't be assumed to be the same running process that's deserialized it, so the mutex is meaningless. It should not be included in the serialization.

Comment: @Adrian so what is the best practice here? I need to serialize an object than contains a mutex field, but it looks like there's no way to specify that gob should ignore a field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595570/go-error-gob-type-sync-mutex-has-no-exported-fields

Answer (score 1):

### Gob Encoding

> Everything seems to work if I make the mutex unexported (by not capitalizing it). I'm curious to understand why this is.

As [Cerise mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595570/go-error-gob-type-sync-mutex-has-no-exported-fields#comment88200352_50595570) there is an [open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5819) for this, but in short it is normally a programming error if you try to encode a struct (such as a mutex) which has no exported fields.

There are some ways to work around this particular problem, though.

You can make the mutex private and wrap the lock/unlock in a public function, rather than reaching into the struct to manipulate the mutex. E.g.

```
func (d *Dog) SetName(name string) {
    d.GobMux.Lock()
    d.Name = name
    d.GobMux.Unlock()
}
```

You can also wrap the type and pull the mutex out:

```
type Dog struct {
    Name string
}

type DogWrapper struct {
    Dog *Dog
    GobMux sync.Mutex
}
```

This is fairly cumbersome if you have many small structs but for a smaller number of more complex structs it might be OK.

Finally, the "correct" way to solve this problem is to write your own GobEncode/Decode routines. There are some sparse examples in the stdlib, such as time.GobEncode, but generally this seems like quite a bit of work.

### Mutexes in General

> ...and make sure that there's no other issue with gobbing an unexported sync.Mutex.

Mutexes are tightly coupled to the Go runtime's in-process memory and scheduler. They help the Go runtime decide which goroutines are allowed to read or write to a particular part of memory, and also decide when those goroutines may be scheduled (i.e. a goroutine waiting on a mutex to unlock will not be scheduled until the mutex is unlocked).

If you use Gob to copy a data structure to another process, the recipient process's runtime has completely different internal state compared to the process that is sending the gob, and as such the mutex cannot be logically transferred. Copying a mutex to another process would be a bit like using Earth GPS coordinates on Mars. They just don't match up.

> when I read back a Dog object from a gob, it looks like the mutex is unlocked regardless of the state of the mutex when it was saved to a gob. Is this behavior I can count on?

As the [documentation for Mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) states, "The zero value for a Mutex is an unlocked mutex." So yes, you can rely on this behavior.

### Other Encoders

In my opinion, despite gob's presence in the stdlib, it does not receive much attention because there are many other mature encoding options available. If gob doesn't meet your needs there are many other options available -- JSON, Cap'n Proto, net/rpc, etc. with different characteristics that may work better for you.